# How do I stop the VS for Mac debugger detaching from an iOS app when the lock button is pressed?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-mac

I am currently developing a Xamarin forms app and its iOS component is hard to debug because whenever I press the lock button on the iPhone, the debugger detaches.

Moreover, there seems to be no way to attach the debugger to a Xamarin iOS/Android process according to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12020/attach-debugger-to-running-app

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean when you lock the iPhone, the debug will stop and lost connection to VS?

Comment: Yes. That is pretty much it.

Comment: Can you try to deploy a blank project on a real device to see whether it will happen?

Comment: is that VS behavior? or general Ios is just killing app running, thats why debugger is detached?